# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) when using emmeans in R

Tags: r, lme4, emmeans

I am running mixed models in R using the lme4 package. I am interested in the effect of a brain stimulation intervention (2 levels: real, placebo) across three sessions (3 levels: 1, 2, 3) and two block types (2 levels: sequential, random) on reaction time (dependent variable).

```
> LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1 <- lmer(Stimulus.RT ~ StimCondition*SessionNrSimplified*BlockType + (1|Subject), data = Conventional_M1)
> LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Stimulus.RT ~ StimCondition * SessionNrSimplified * BlockType +      (1 | Subject)
   Data: Conventional_M1
REML criterion at convergence: 1290940
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept)  48.54  
 Residual             137.13  
Number of obs: 101795, groups:  Subject, 45
Fixed Effects:
                                              (Intercept)                                          StimConditionSham  
                                                  428.885                                                     -5.211  
                                     SessionNrSimplified2                                       SessionNrSimplified3  
                                                  -41.386                                                    -14.354  
                                       BlockTypeTrialList                     StimConditionSham:SessionNrSimplified2  
                                                  -29.535                                                     13.798  
                   StimConditionSham:SessionNrSimplified3                       StimConditionSham:BlockTypeTrialList  
                                                   22.106                                                     10.473  
                  SessionNrSimplified2:BlockTypeTrialList                    SessionNrSimplified3:BlockTypeTrialList  
                                                   -8.239                                                    -39.049  
StimConditionSham:SessionNrSimplified2:BlockTypeTrialList  StimConditionSham:SessionNrSimplified3:BlockTypeTrialList  
                                                  -18.722                                                    -24.607  
> car::Anova(LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1, type=3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Stimulus.RT
                                                Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)                                 3131.9700  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
StimCondition                                  2.1334  1   0.144122    
SessionNrSimplified                          141.6687  2  < 2.2e-16 ***
BlockType                                    118.5960  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
StimCondition:SessionNrSimplified             18.6116  2  9.089e-05 ***
StimCondition:BlockType                        7.4732  1   0.006262 ** 
SessionNrSimplified:BlockType                107.9022  2  < 2.2e-16 ***
StimCondition:SessionNrSimplified:BlockType   21.3060  2  2.363e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The model converges fine and Type III Wald Chi Square tests are no issue, using the car package.
However, recently, even when running relatively simple models (large datasets), I receive the following error when running emmeans:

```
> LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1_emm <- emmeans(LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1, pairwise ~ StimCondition*SessionNrSimplified*BlockType)
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'chol2inv': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'chol': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'forceSymmetric': Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 102
> LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1_emm
Error: object 'LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1_emm' not found
```

As I have not encountered this error before, I figured it may be a compatibility issue of the emmeans package with the latest version of R. I re-ran my script in different versions of R (4.1.3, 4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0), but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this, please?

Comment: Show the call you used for emmeans(). Also, use the {} widget to format the output so it is readable.

Comment: @RussLenth , thank you for your response. I edited my question to make it more clear. Any ideas as to what causes the problem?

Comment: Hmmm. All I can say is that this error occurs somewhere besides in the `emmeans` code; perhaps it occurs in the **lmerMod** package when it tries to retrieve the covariance matrix or something. Also, later in the error message we see `Cholmod error 'problem too large'` which suggests to me just that. I wonder, if you subset the data somehow, if the error goes away.

Comment: You could also try `RG <- emmeans::ref_grid(LMER_model3_SSLE_Conventional_M1, mode = "asymp")` and if that works, it'd suggest that the error is in the code that implements the Satterthwaite d.f. method.